# Как настроить скролл вниз/вверх ?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать следующую реализацию:

Изначально пользователь находится в шапке, при попытке скролла, его автоматически скроллит к следующей секции и дальше если он скроллит вниз, то он делает это уже сам, а если вверх, то его обратно автоматически скроллит в самый вверх и дальше уже повторяется всё.

Смог написать только скролл вниз, а как обратно и опять по кругу, что-то не выходит.

```js
var scrollNum = 1;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log($(this).scrollTop());
  var scrlTop = $('header').height() - 20;
  
  if($(this).scrollTop() > scrollNum){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.next-section').offset().top }, 1000);
    scrollNum = 9999999;
  }
  if($(this).scrollTop() == scrlTop){
    console.log('скролл вверх');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('header').offset().top }, 1000);
    scrollNum = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.next-section {
  height: 600px;
  background: red;
}

.some-sect {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="next-section"></div>

<div class="some-sect"></div>
<div class="some-sect"></div>
<div class="some-sect"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ты хочешь, при каждом скроле скролить по одной секции?

Comment: Нет, я хочу только от хедера к next-section и обратно, остальное сам пользователь скроллит

Answer (score 1):

Присвой каждому блоку свой id и на евент скролла назнач переход к следующему **id** (по **якорю**) в зависимости от стороны скроллинга)
Можешь посмотреть на библиотеку **FullPage.js** или вообще ее использовать :)

Comment: Мне не подойдет подобная библиотека, мне нужен скролл только вниз к следующей секции и вверх обратно, а если в самый низ нужно, то пользователь сам листает. 

Я не знаю как отловить события скролла вверх, находясь во второй секции.

Comment: Вот хороший учебник по js:
https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll

Comment: А вот как отловить сторону:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/124327/

Comment: если помогло, пожалуйста, отметь как ответ)

Comment: Вы скинули хорошие статейки, но почитав, я мало, что нашел для решения своего вопроса)